# Remind vs Remember

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice

I was thinking about the absent distinction in German between `remember` and `remind`. To my knowledge, they are both formulated with\translated to `erinnern`.

**For example:**

- *"Can you remind me to open the windows when we get home?"*

  > Kannst du mich daran erinnern die Fenster aufzumachen, wenn wir heimkommen?

**or**

- *"When I asked him, he could no longer remember."*

  > Als ich ihn gefragt habe, konnte er sich nicht mehr daran erinnern.

---

So far everything is fine, but what happens if someone wants to remind **himself** something?

**For instance, how would the following be translated:**

- *"In the morning I have to **remind myself** to lock the door."*

Comment: You would rather not *remind* yourself, but *interdict to forget*: "Morgens darf ich nicht vergessen, die Tür abzuschließen"

Comment: "remind" is "erinnern", "remember" is "sich erinnern".

Comment: @IQV Then one can just say *"Ich muss mich morgens daran erinnern, die Tür abzuschließen."*, right?

Comment: @Eller Explaining *why* would be very thoughtful of you.

Answer (score 8):

Wenn sich jemand wie in deinem Beispiel selbst an etwas erinnern will, dann verwendest du besser *denken*:

> Ich muss morgens daran *denken*, die Tür abzuschließen.

Comment: `Remember to log out`: Denk dran, dich abzumelden. `Remind me later`: Erinner mich später. `Mind the step`: Vergiss die Stufe nicht.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Ich verstehe deinen Kommentar nicht. Mein Beitrag bezieht sich nur auf Erinnerungen an sich selbst. Was haben deine Beispiele damit zu tun?

Answer (score 2):

> Ich muss **mich** morgens daran **erinnern**, die Tür abzuschließen.

is of course a valid translation of

> In the morning I have to **remind myself** to lock the door.

However, it also is a valid translation of

> In the morning I have to **remember** to lock the door.

If you explicitly want to express the meaning of "remind" ("external" refresh of memory - figuratively done to oneself) in contrast to "remember" (internal access to memory), you can add a "selbst":

> Ich muss **mich** morgens ***selbst*** daran **erinnern**, die Tür abzuschließen.

e.g. if normally someone or something else reminds you, but now you have to do the reminding (and thus not remembering) yourself.